# Create mini Data Frames using large Data Frames's row values -Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` Data Frame that I read in from an Excel file. Since row 1 in Excel file had repeating values such as `245, 245, 245`, I read them as `pd.read_excel(file, 'myfile', header = None)`, so I can prevent pandas creating headers `245, 245.1, 245.2` etc.

Here is my `df` looks like:

```
    0             1      2            3                 4
0   245           245   245           867               867
1   Reddit        NaN   NaN           Facebook          NaN
2   ColumnNeeded  NaN   ColumnValue   ColumnNeeded      ColumnValue
3   RedditInsight NaN   C             FacbookInsights   A
4   RedditText    NaN   H             FacbookText       L
```

I need my output like this (`needed_df`),

```
    ID      Company     ColumnNeeded    ColumnValue
0   245     Reddit      RedditInsight   C
1   245     Reddit      RedditText      H
2   867     Facebook    FacbookInsight  A
3   867     Facebook    FacbookText     L
```

Not sure, how to go about this in `pandas`. I tried to take all the unique values in Row 1 from `df`.

```
id_s = []
for i in df.iloc[0]:
    id_s.append(i)
print(set(id_s))
```

list of unique_ids'

```
unique_id = list(set(id_s))
print(unique_id )
>> [867,245]
```

And then I wanted to iterate through `df's` row 1 and find all the matching values in `unique_id` list and then split them into a separate mini dataframes.

I could not get that work. My thinking was to create mini data frames, mini df1 i.e.:

```
    0             1     2            
0   245           245   245           
1   Reddit        NaN   NaN           
2   ColumnNeeded  NaN   ColumnValue   
3   RedditInsight NaN   C             
4   RedditText    NaN   H
```

mini df2:

```
    0                 1
0   867               867
1   Facebook          NaN
2   ColumnNeeded      ColumnValue
3   FacbookInsights   A
4   FacbookText       L
```

I am thinking to do manipulation (possibly using a function, so I can apply to all mini dfs) to these mini dataframes and finally append them to a big dataframe. Or is there any other ideas or ways to do this to get my output dataframe?

Comment: @user9431057 Hey let me know if my answer works

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame was created like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[245,245,245,867,867], ['Reddit', np.nan, np.nan,'Facebook',np.nan], ['ColumnNeeded',np.nan, 'ColumnValue', 'ColumnNeeded','ColumnValue'],
                   ['RedditInsight', np.nan, 'C', 'FacebookInsights', 'A'], ['RedditText', np.nan, 'H', 'FacbookText', 'L']])
```

Your DataFrame looks like this:

```
               0      1            2                 3            4
0            245  245.0          245               867          867
1         Reddit    NaN          NaN          Facebook          NaN
2   ColumnNeeded    NaN  ColumnValue      ColumnNeeded  ColumnValue
3  RedditInsight    NaN            C  FacebookInsights            A
4     RedditText    NaN            H       FacbookText            L
```

and now the code.

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #Grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #Take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #Set the header row as the df header


#Drop the column with all NaNs
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.T #Transpose

#Must find a way to do this part programtically
#Manually changing the index currently

df.index = [245.0, 245.1, 867.0, 867.1] 

iPrev = ""

l1 = []
for i in df.index:

    indexNow = str(i)[:3]
    #print(indexNow)
    if iPrev == indexNow:

        #print(df.at[i, 3], df.at[i, 4])
        l2.append(df.at[i, 3])

        l3.append(df.at[i, 4])

        l1.append(l2)
        l1.append(l3)
        l2 = []
        l3 = []
    else:

        iPrev = indexNow

        l2 = [i, df.at[i, 1], df.at[i, 3]]
        l3 = [i, df.at[i, 1], df.at[i, 4]]
        #print(l2)

result = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns = ['ID','Company','ColumnNeeded','ColumnValue'])

print(result)
```

Gives

```
      ID   Company      ColumnNeeded ColumnValue
0  245.0    Reddit     RedditInsight           C
1  245.0    Reddit        RedditText           H
2  867.0  Facebook  FacebookInsights           A
3  867.0  Facebook       FacbookText           L
```

Comment: `df.index = [245.0, 245.1, 867.0, 867.1] ` has one missing value `245.2`. And it gives me a different answer :(

Comment: @user9431057 The code should work provided, your DataFrame is like the one you posted `Here is my df looks like:` in your question! It looks like you changed the way you read it in! My answer will work for how your DataFrame originally looked.

Comment: @user9431057 Could you also run the first paragraph of code! and do `print(df)` and let me know if the DataFrame displayed is the same?

Comment: I am getting 6 rows of results and `ColumnValues` C,H are in ID and Facebook's one looks okay!

Comment: @user9431057 How about you upload your excel, and I'll take a look at it? Send a Google Drive link!