# Create Mini/Sub Data Frames Using a Big Pandas DataFrame's Column Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I posted a question earlier in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197613/create-mini-data-frames-using-large-data-framess-row-values-pandas/51198169?noredirect=1#comment89378475_51198169). I thought I would ask this question separate as this is just one operation to divide a big data frame into separate mini/sub dataframes.

Say, I have this `df`:

```
    245           245   245           867               867
0   Reddit        NaN   NaN           Facebook          NaN
1   ColumnNeeded  NaN   ColumnValue   ColumnNeeded      ColumnValue
2   RedditInsight NaN   C             FacbookInsights   A
3   RedditText    NaN   H             FacbookText       L
```

Now, I want two different data frames like this,
`df1`:

```
    245           245   245           
0   Reddit        NaN   NaN           
1   ColumnNeeded  NaN   ColumnValue   
2   RedditInsight NaN   C             
3   RedditText    NaN   H
```

`df2`:

```
    867               867
0   Facebook          NaN
1   ColumnNeeded      ColumnValue
2   FacbookInsights   A
3   FacbookText       L
```

Basically, I want to create sub data frames by it's unique values of headers. 
I was trying to create a list like this:

```
list_of_dfs = [set(i) for i in df.columns]
```

This returns just column values,

```
[{245}, {245}, {245}, {867}, {867}]
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: `[df[i] for i in df.columns.unique()]` ?

Comment: @Harv Ipan this works. Thanks. I added `reset_index()` and even nicer.  `[df[i].reset_index(drop=True) for i in df.columns.unique()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to reset index and get sub dataframes for each unique name of columns, you need:

```
[df[i].reset_index(drop=True) for i in df.columns.unique()]
```

Output:

```
[             
              245 245          245
 0         Reddit NaN          NaN
 1   ColumnNeeded NaN  ColumnValue
 2  RedditInsight NaN            C
 3     RedditText NaN            H,                

                867          867
 0         Facebook          NaN
 1     ColumnNeeded  ColumnValue
 2  FacbookInsights            A
 3      FacbookText            L
]
```